# Уважаемые знатоки Javascript и jquery требуется помощь!

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Уважаемые, прошу помочь, мне нужно сделать плавающее меню как на сайте [Ситилинк](https://www.citilink.ru/)
я уже бъюсь над этим скриптом неделю, из за нехватка знания голову сломал.

Постоянно что то не выходит, побывал разные способы. Но хотел бы понять как именно на этом сайте https://www.citilink.ru/

Могу поделиться своими наработками, но увы они не работают так как у Ситилинк

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           var origTop = $('#bx_sidebar').offset().top;
            var origBottom = origTop + $('#bx_sidebar').height();
            var scrollDir = 0;
            var scrollLast = 0;
            var weirdOffset = 0;

            $(window).scroll(function() {

                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                var curTop = $('#bx_sidebar').offset().top;
                var curBottom = curTop + $('#bx_sidebar').height();

                if(scrollTop > scrollLast) {
                    scrollDir = 1;
                } else if(scrollTop < scrollLast) {
                    scrollDir = 0;
                }
                scrollLast = scrollTop;

                if(scrollDir == 1) {
                    if(scrollBottom >= origBottom && scrollBottom >= curBottom) {
                        $('#bx_sidebar').animate({
                            top: scrollBottom -  $('#bx_sidebar').outerHeight() + weirdOffset
                        }, 0);
                    }
                }

                if(scrollDir == 0) {
                    if(scrollTop <= origTop) {

                        $('#bx_sidebar').css('top', '-' + (origTop + weirdOffset) + 'px');

                    } else if(scrollTop <= curTop) {

                        $('#bx_sidebar').animate({
                            top: scrollTop + weirdOffset
                        }, 0);

                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Данный код установлен на сайте e-geek.ru, но при работе боковая колонка прыгает, и растягивает длину body

Comment: чем данный вопрос отличается от [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/668460/186999)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать плавающий сайдбар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668460/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80)